# We are unable to upload this Certificate file because it is invalid. Please check the file and try again

Tags: ios, certificate

I've already checked every single post in this forum, but nothing seems useful.
I've generated my development certificate on apple site without any problem, but now I'm not able to generate the distribution one.

I'm not new to these things, but this is the first time that a thing like this happens to me. I've tried to change browser and use safari, but it doesn't work.

Any advice?

Comment: A little more detail would make it easier to help. What steps did you follow? What did you get as a result? Which step failed? Set side by side with Apple's documentation we should be able to get you a solution.

Answer (score 17):

I just had this problem. I'd left the Common Name: field blank. I filled it in and the error went away.

Comment: For me just the opposite worked : putting a name in the "Common name" field. So weird ...

Comment: How could that be opposite from yours? He told the same thing you did.
Any ways, and yes, following it my error is gone too. Thanks @Mark Bridges

Comment: filling the common name  worked for me.

Comment: filling the common name also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the right instruction to get a certificate?
It sounds like you made a wrong certificate and Apple can't read it since you already tried safari.

More info is here: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/20341-generate-submit-a-csr.html
And in the Apple Dev portal itself.

Comment: Alerady read that, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to make sure that the you make sure to put an email address in the "CA Email Address" field.